# JavaScript: Merge the elements with the same key into the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to find duplicate elements of an array and 2 arrays of duplicate elements.

```
array = [
  ["41",{asd:"1"}],
  ["41",{asd:"2"}],
  ["42",{asd:"1"}],
  ["42",{asd:"2"}]
]
```

And the result I want

```
result=[
  ["41",{asd:"1"},{asd:"2"}],
  ["42",{asd:"1"},{asd:"2"}],
]
```

I have to use core JavaScript. Frameworks are not allowed.

Comment: what goes wrong with your code?

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry guy! This is my first time using it, I will learn from it for the next time

Answer (score 0):

[`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) over the array. Extract the key and object from the array in each iteration. If the key doesn't exist on the accumulator add it and set it's value to `[key]`, and then push the object into it. Then use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get the output you need.

```js
const arr = [
  ["41",{asd:"1"}],
  ["41",{asd:"2"}],
  ["42",{asd:"1"}],
  ["42",{asd:"2"}]
];

const out = arr.reduce((acc, c) => {
  const [key, obj] = c;
  acc[key] = acc[key] || [key];
  acc[key].push(obj);
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(out));
```

Comment: Thank you, I have solved the problem. Thanks